# Чтение pptx PHP (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

Как прочесть файл презентации .ppt/pptx в laravel? или же какие нибудь сторонние библиотеки/расширения?

Comment: Во-первых, что вы хотите сделать с презентацией? Конвертировать во что-то? Во-вторых, пробовали ли вы самостоятельно поискать плагин? Для Laravel подходят и обычные PHP-библиотеки. По запросу `power point Laravel` в Google третьим результатом идет вот этот плагин-обертка над CloudConvert: https://github.com/robbiepaul/cloudconvert-laravel